# MongoDB failover reasons

Tags: mongodb, failover

I have a replica set on MongoDB with 3 members - primary, secondary and arbiter. One day I came and saw that primary and secondary have switched. I'd like to find a reason for the failover that caused the elections. Please advise me how and where I can find what caused it. I looked in the logs and I found only this:

> 2015-03-03T12:18:41.540-0500 [rsHealthPoll] replset info
>   my_server:27017 thinks that we are down 2015-03-03T12:18:41.540-0500
>   [rsHealthPoll] replSet member my_another_server:27017 is now in state
>   PRIMARY 2015-03-03T12:18:41.540-0500 [rsMgr] stepping down; another
>   primary was elected more recently

Thanks

Comment: Check any OS/network logs or monitoring tools to find out why the primary believed it was down.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you can do to start

Run the following on the old `PRIMARY`

```
var dt = new Date(db.serverStatus().localTime - db.serverStatus().uptime*1000).toString() ; dt
```

This will print the exact time `mongod` was started.

`PRIMARY` failover was triggered `2015-03-03T12:18:41.540-0500`.

- If `dt` is close to `2015-03-03T12:18:41.540-0500`

  - `mongod` crashed or was restarted
  - Check the `mongod` Log File on the old `PRIMARY` for that same timeframe
- If `dt` is not close to `2015-03-03T12:18:41.540-0500`

  - `mongod` is still running fine
  - The old `PRIMARY` simply became unreachable
  - Check network logs along port 27017